# How to calculate turret position after rotation

Tags: mathematics, javascript, rotation

I'm trying to make a tank character for my game but I couldn't do the math of firing bullets from turret instead of center of the tank.

I tried some Stack Overflow solutions but I couldn't understand them correctly or they weren't related to my issue.

```
this.angle = (rotation in radians) + Math.PI / 2
var x = -40 * Math.sin(this.angle) - -40 * Math.cos(this.angle);
var y = -40 * Math.cos(this.angle) + -40 * Math.sin(this.angle);

turretX = turretX - x;
turretY = turretY - y;
```

Now, as you can imagine, [the position is always 40px wrong](https://prnt.sc/n1wg5d). That's expected since I try to change values of both x and y regardless of whether they're already correct or not.

How can I get the correct x, y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in a random stackoverflow post, not sure if there's better ways to do this but it works. Feel free to post your way if you think that's better.

```
var turretX =
  (0 - 0) * Math.cos(rotation) - (40 - 0) * Math.sin(rotation) + 0;
var turretY =
  (40 - 0) * Math.cos(rotation) + (0 - 0) * Math.sin(rotation) + 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the angle and position of the turret, then it's simply

```
x = turretPosX + cos(angle) * barrelLength
y = turretPosY + sin(angle) * barrelLength
```